# Why does WatiN Freeze the application

Tags: c#, watin

I have been working on a project and noticed the watin library freezing the application. Here is the code:

```
using(var browser = new IE(url))
{
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
     {
          browser.Link(Find.ById("overridelink")).Click();
     }
}
```

The code above works fine if the ID "overidelink" attribute is found. If its not found the whole application freezes up. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You could break into the debugger to see where it hangs. Or you could profile the application and see where the performance goes.

Comment: put a try/catch around the browser statement and step it in the debugger.  if "overridelink" doesn't exist, maybe Find.ById is returning NULL or throwing an exception?  can Link accept a NULL?  i would recommend make it a multiple line statement and skipping the click() if the value is not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if it's exists and then excecute the click

```
if (Browser.Link(Find.ById("overridelink")).Exists)
{
    Browser.Link(Find.ById("overridelink")).Click();
}
```